Android resource linking failed: catroid
While i was building my Pocket Code (CATROID) copy in last version of Android Studio and last version of plugins, i was been in dead end, because i cant fix that error at least 2 days! So ChatGPT cant help me, human will help better.
Here is my console error:
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6314}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6315: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_motion_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_motion_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6315}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6316: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_sound_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_sound_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6318}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6319: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_pen_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_pen_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6320}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6321: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_legonxt_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_legonxt_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6321}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6322: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_phiro_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_phiro_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6323}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6324: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_look_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_look_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6324}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6325: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_raspberrypi_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_raspberrypi_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6326}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6327: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_your_brick_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_your_brick_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6328}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6329: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_recently_used_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_recently_used_neg) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6397}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6398: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_motion_pos (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_motion_pos) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":6398}}],"original":"ERROR: C:\\Users\\tuner\\Downloads\\Catroid-develop\\catroid\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\catroidDebug\\mergeCatroidDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values\\values.xml:6399: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_sound_pos (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_sound_pos) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
Resolve mutations for :catroid:mergeExtDexCatroidDebug (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started.
:catroid:mergeExtDexCatroidDebug (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started.

Execution failed for task ':catroid:processCatroidDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR: C:\Users\tuner\Downloads\Catroid-develop\catroid\build\intermediates\incremental\catroidDebug\mergeCatroidDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:6315: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_motion_neg (aka com.glitch.code:drawable/ic_motion_neg) not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 11s
30 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 21 up-to-date
Watched directory hierarchies: [C:\Users\tuner\Downloads\Catroid-develop]

Note: my resources is exist in drawable
I was expecting a normal build with just changed package name and changed icon of app.
